# Reset margins in the wireframe plot using lattice R package

Tags: r, lattice, margins, wireframe

I am trying to plot a 3D graph in lattice using `wireframe`. I want to reset the margins between the 3d plot and the R window,

The top margins is too big and this wastes lots of space when I convert it into postscript files. I am trying to reduce to margins.

I tried the following R code `par(mar=c(4,3,3,1)+0.1).`

However nothing is happening.

Comment: par() is a function of traditional graphics system, not lattice. Also give an example of your code in order to be able to help. Your problem could probabily easily be solved by setting the aspect ratio or maybe by setting the zoom but in lack of example it is hard to figure out which one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet, adapted from https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-January/123556.html. It worked for me.

```
library(lattice)
theme.novpadding <- list(
    layout.heights = list(
        top.padding = 0,
        main.key.padding = 0,
        key.axis.padding = 0,
        axis.xlab.padding = 0,
        xlab.key.padding = 0,
        key.sub.padding = 0,
        bottom.padding = 0
    ),
    layout.widths = list(
        left.padding = 0,
        key.ylab.padding = 0,
        ylab.axis.padding = 0,
        axis.key.padding = 0,
        right.padding = 0
    )
)
wireframe(volcano, shade = TRUE,
          aspect = c(61/87, 0.4),
          #par.settings = theme.novpadding, # uncomment this
          light.source = c(10,0,10))
```